# Use a command to enlarge cells in a table

Tags: tables

I have used a code to create tables, however, when I try to enlarge a cell that line of the image disappears. Any ideas to fix it?

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{multirow} % para las tablas
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Comando & Función & Clase \\
\hline \hline \hline
lsusb -tv & Mostrar los Dispositivos USB & Información del Sistema \\ \hline
clock -w & Guardar los cambios de fecha en la BIOS. & Información del Sistema \\ \hline
shutdown -h 
\\
hours:minutes & Apagado planificado del sistema & Apagar \\  \hline
shutdown -c & Cancelar el apagado planificado & Apagar \\ \hline
reboot & Reiniciar el sistema & Reiniciar \\ \hline
ls -l & Mostrar los detalles de un Fichero & Archivos \\ \hline
ls *[0-9]* & Mostrar los ficheros y carpetas que contienen números & Archivos \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And this appears to me:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the cell delimiter `&` to complete the unused row:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | >{\ttfamily}l | l | l | }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Comando} & Función                               & Clase \\
  \hline \hline \hline
  lsusb -tv     & Mostrar los Dispositivos USB                          & Información del Sistema \\ \hline
  clock -w      & Guardar los cambios de fecha en la BIOS.              & Información del Sistema \\ \hline
  shutdown -h   &                                                       & \\
  hours:minutes & Apagado planificado del sistema                       & Apagar \\ \hline
  shutdown -c   & Cancelar el apagado planificado                       & Apagar \\ \hline
  reboot        & Reiniciar el sistema                                  & Reiniciar \\ \hline
  ls -l         & Mostrar los detalles de un Fichero                    & Archivos \\ \hline
  ls *[0-9]*    & Mostrar los ficheros y carpetas que contienen números & Archivos \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Avoid the use of excessive `\hline`s and vertical rules since the `tabular` construction already supports delineation. Consider using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\ttfamily}l l l }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Comando} & Función                                 & Clase                   \\
  \midrule
  lsusb -tv     & Mostrar los Dispositivos USB                          & Información del Sistema \\
  clock -w      & Guardar los cambios de fecha en la BIOS.              & Información del Sistema \\
  shutdown -h   &                                                       &                         \\
  hours:minutes & Apagado planificado del sistema                       & Apagar                  \\
  shutdown -c   & Cancelar el apagado planificado                       & Apagar                  \\
  reboot        & Reiniciar el sistema                                  & Reiniciar               \\
  ls -l         & Mostrar los detalles de un Fichero                    & Archivos                \\
  ls *[0-9]*    & Mostrar los ficheros y carpetas que contienen números & Archivos                \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is this what you required?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{multirow} % para las tablas
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} \hline
Comando & Función & Clase \\ \hline \hline \hline
lsusb -tv & Mostrar los Dispositivos USB & Información del Sistema \\ \hline
clock -w & Guardar los cambios de fecha en la BIOS. & Información del Sistema \\ \hline
shutdown -h &&                                                              \\
hours:minutes & Apagado planificado del sistema & Apagar \\  \hline
shutdown -c & Cancelar el apagado planificado & Apagar \\ \hline
reboot & Reiniciar el sistema & Reiniciar \\ \hline
ls -l & Mostrar los detalles de un Fichero & Archivos \\ \hline
ls *[0-9]* & Mostrar los ficheros y carpetas que contienen números & Archivos \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```